# Linking local node.js module inside local Meteor Package

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm in the process of developing a Meteor package, that has a dependency on a node module. This module is also, under development, so right now it's just a local folder.

Looking around, it seems that adding

`Npm.depends({ "npmmodulename": "x.x.x"});`

on the `package.js` file, it should be enough, but how do I do this, when the npm module is local? I tried adding the path to the module, instead of the version, but I had no luck...

Can this be actually done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify an Npm.depends clause because your node package is not yet published to npmjs.org so it doesn't matter.

Let's assume your node package is in "my-project/packages/my-package/node-package".
You can reference it from your meteor package like this :

my-project/packages/my-package/server.js :

```
var nodePackage=Npm.require("../../../../../packages/my-package/node-package");
```

All the ../.. stuff is needed because the current working directory of a meteor node process is "my-project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server".

Note that using this technique, meteor doesn't take care of building your node package, so you need to manually "npm install" it each time you modify it's inner dependencies.

Comment: I see, well, thanks I was hoping I could just tell meteorite where the npm package was, and it would set everything up.