# How to specify local npm modules in meteor packages

Tags: meteor, npm

I have an application which uses a Meteor with npm module. So I have a packages/mymodule/package.js file which contains:

```
Npm.depends({my_npm_module:"my_npm_module_version"});
```

Upon lauching Meteor app, my_npm_module will be installed to packages/mymodule/.npm from npm repository. Now lets say I want to develop my_npm_module on my local machine. How can I force Meteor to use my local directory for my_npm_module, What should I do i my_npm_module source is modified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking local node.js module inside local Meteor Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430119/linking-local-node-js-module-inside-local-meteor-package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a local Npm module it may not be necessary to do this.

Simply use `var module = Npm.require('<absolute path to npm module>');` anywhere on your server side.

Comment: Right, or in Meteor: `import module from 'relative_path_to_module';`

Comment: Does this also work for modules that are added to the 'node_modules' folder with `npm link`?